# Angular 4 ngx boostrap pagination working local mode but not production mode

Tags: angular, azure, webpack, production-environment, ngx-bootstrap

My pagination works locally but not when i try to publish it to azure (if i comment the pagination html, then i can publish it on azure )
My html component

```
    <div class="pagination-position">
<pagination [boundaryLinks]="true" (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)" [itemsPerPage]="itemsPerPage" [totalItems]="totalItems"
            [(ngModel)]="currentPage" class="pagination-sm" previousText="&lsaquo;" nextText="&rsaquo;" firstText="&laquo;" lastText="&raquo;"></pagination>
```

The import from app module

```
 import { PaginationModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/pagination';
```

+

```
    imports: [(other imports)... PaginationModule.forRoot() ]
```

The error :
Module parse failed: C:\Users......\$$_gendir\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\pagination\pagination.component.ngfactory.ts Unexpected token (14:32)

You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

What may be the problem ?
I tried with ngx-pagination, ngx-bootstrap/pagination, remove / add again ngx-bootstrap, npm install.

Comment: can you using `ng serve --prod`

Comment: I made a predefined standard project from visual studio ( .net core + angular ) and i can't run ng serve even though i installed angular cli.

Comment: Nobody has an answer? This is the command that gets me the error : node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod     Module parse failed.You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    | import * as i3 from '@angular/forms';
    | import * as i4 from 'ngx-bootstrap/pagination/pagination.config';

Comment: I see that every component i use from ngx bootstrap gets the same message. I need a loader.